# I am getting this warning "comparison of constant ‘10’ with boolean expression is always true"

Tags: c, loops

I am unable to escape from the loop by entering newline.

```
int input(char str[], int n)
{
    int ch, i = 0;
    while ((ch == getchar()) != '\n')
        if (i < n)
            str[i++] = ch;
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: `ch == getchar()` is a boolean expression. It is equal to either 0 or 1, and will never equal `'\n'` (which is 10). You probably meant `ch = getchar()`

Comment: here the main function: int main()
{
 char str[100];
 int n = input(str, 5);
 printf("%d %s", n, str);
}

Comment: @Bloodknofsky don't put code in a comment, instead [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Comment: There is no question in your... question... Is your problem the warning or the fact that you can't get out of the loop ? Please edit your post.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace `==` with `=` because you want to assign `getchar()` to `ch` and not compare it.

```
int input(char str[], int n)
{
    int ch, i = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
        if (i < n)
            str[i++] = ch;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo forgot `{` symbols in your code. Any control structure such `while` and `if` of more than one instruction line should be coded like this :

```
while(condition){
  instruction 1;
  instruction 2;
  ...
}
```

By the way your `i` is always 0 and your `n` does not change within your function.

EDIT: The reason you obtain your warning have been answered by someone else.

Comment: It is not actually required that the parenthesis need to be in this case as `str[i++] = ch;` belongs to the one and only `if` statement. Although I personally recommend this style too.

Comment: Indeed so I wrote "control structure ... of more than one line". He seems to not know the rule at all so I thought it was a good idea explain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ch == getchar())
```

You use `==` instead of `=`.

`==` is used as boolean operator for checking if the left hand operand equals right hand one.

Thus, the loop will never terminate because you compare `0` or `1` (which is the result of `(ch == getchar())` with `\n` whose ASCII value is `10`.

That´s what the error is saying.

`=` is used for assignment and required to assign the character fetched by `getchar()` to `ch`.

---

This is the corrected version:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
     if (i < n)
     str[i++] = ch;
}
```